# Navigation remains same when selecting list

Tags: 2010, list, sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-foundation

I have SharePoint list named "XXXXXXXXXXXX". when select any list item then the navigation removed and the options pane will appear. i want the navigation remains same even if i select list or list item.
please reply as soon as possible.

I want this when i select list/list item :

[image]

I get this when i select list/list item :

[image]

Comment: have you tried adding
`$(".s4-wpcell").removeAttr('onkeyup').removeAttr('onmouseup');`
like described here [link](http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/11886/blog-how-to-avoid-list-tools-in-ribbon-when-clicking-on-text)

Answer (score 1):

Basically if I understand correctly you want to have the navigation still be available (beign seen) even if the ribbon is expanded when selecting a list item or list web part.

Basically it is still on the page, but it is behind the ribbon, so i would suggest you play with css and move the navigation more down, or let the ribbon appear lower. So its up to you to chose, but the solution is changing css.

Also you might investigate the javascript behind when expending the ribbon, so you might perfrom some extra task like changing css styles on the time when the ribbon is expanded and putting everything back when it is closed.

Comment: Shkipper, some examples with css and javascript if possible will be good... I am following this post, I want to know the answer too - since I feel this requirement many times in my app as well

Answer (score 0):

That's called the ribbon, and it lets you take actions on items. If you select an item, the assumption is that you'll want to do something with it.

I would highly discourage changing this behavior, as it is the same across SharePoint for all lists. The buttons on the ribbon are permission trimmed, so users will only be able to do things they are allowed to do.